# jQuery: hiding and fadeIn divs with less code

Tags: jquery, performance

my first steps with jQuery. The code below works, however I'm sure it's totally bloated.

Here's the scenario: There is a page with 9 products. Each time the user clicks on a link (`item[x]`), all the content within the general `#contentdiv` is supposed to hide and the new content fading in.

The new content consists of a general product info (`#product[x]`) and an additional `.info` div class (`.info1`, `.info2`).

I'm sure many beginners are wondering as to how to write this code more efficient with less bloat. Any ideas ?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contentbox">   
<div id="product1">blah</div><!-- is displayed on pageload -->

<div id="product2" style="display:none;">blah</div>
<div id="product3" style="display:none;">blah</div>
<div id="product4" style="display:none;">blah</div>  
<div id="product5" style="display:none;">blah</div>
<div id="product6" style="display:none;">blah</div>    
<div id="product7" style="display:none;">blah</div>
<div id="product8" style="display:none;">blah</div>       
<div id="product9" style="display:none;">blah</div>

<div class="info1">blah</div><!-- is displayed on pageload -->                  
<div class="info2" style="display:none;">blah</div>

</div><!-- End of #contentbox -->
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#item-1').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product1').fadeIn(200);$('.info1').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-2').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product2').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-3').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product3').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-4').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product4').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-5').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product5').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-6').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product6').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-7').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product7').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-8').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product8').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
$('#item-9').click(function (){$('#contentbox').children().hide();$('#product9').fadeIn(200);$('.info2').fadeIn(200);});
```

Comment: Did you mean to have info2 on all but the first click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your whole code with

```
 $('[id^="item-"]').click(function(){
      var num = this.id.slice(5);
      $('#contentbox').children().hide();
      $('#product'+num).add('.info'+num).fadeIn(200);
 });
```

Explanations :

- `[id^="item-"]` is a selector for elements whose id starts with "item-"
- `this.id.slice(5)` returns the end of the id (past the fifth character)

I suppose, like mplugjan, that your example was slightly wrong on the .info parts. If it's right, replace `'.info'+num` with `'.info'+(num==1?1:2)`.

Comment: The `.info` part is slightly different in OPs example.

Comment: Likely the example needs updating

Comment: chnage `$('#product'+num).fadeIn(200);$('.info'+num).fadeIn(200);` to `$('#product'+num,'.info'+num).fadeIn(200);`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this, either like *dystroy*'s answer.

Or you could also solve this by adding `data` tags to your *item*

```
<a class="item" data-product="1" data-info="1">item1</a>
<a class="item" data-product="2" data-info="2">item2</a>
<a class="item" data-product="3" data-info="2">item3</a>
```

And then you could write your js code that way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function(){
   var infoNo = $(this).data("info"),
       productNo = $(this).data("product");

   $('#contentbox').children().hide();
   $('#product'+productNo).fadeIn(200);
   $('.info'+infoNo).fadeIn(200);
});
```

This allows you define for each item individually which product and info should be displayed.

(If the ids for product and info are the same, and it was a mistake in your question, you would only require one `data` tag).